# Automated Releases based on EMAIL Approval in TFS

Tags: tfs, automation, devops

So this might not be something new but i couldn't find anything on google so posting it here

In short I am trying to tie change management and release management without using TFS API.

We have TFS configured to deploy 3 times a day to QA automatically. However, what i am trying to implement for prod is an approval process. We use ServiceNow (SNOW) to all change management. Once a change is approved in SNOW to be deployed on a specific date, SNOW can send email notifications to pre-defined mailbox lets say one which TFS can hook into. Once TFS receives the email, it should deploy the build to prod. I am clear on SNOW part about how to trigger the email, however is there way to kick off a deployment based on email without using TFS API. Or should i be look at chef or puppet for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider ServiceNow [Outbound REST Webservices](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-application-development/page/integrate/outbound-rest/concept/c_OutboundRESTWebService.html) option?. ServiceNow can call REST APIs on specific conditions. In your case, it could be ServiceNow calling TFS release API when the ticket is approved and is in the change window.

Comment: Thanks this is what we are going with